# Dropbear equivalent to rsync with ssh proxy command

Tags: ssh, proxy, rsync, dropbear

I am trying to guess the dropbear equivalent to this regular rsync command (using ssh with a proxy)

```
rsync -avz --delete -e "ssh -o 'ProxyCommand ssh user@proxyhost exec nc %h %p 2>/dev/null'" /tmp/a-folder user@host:/tmp
```

According to my search, it is all about the `-J` option in `dropbear ssh` but I can't manage to get it work.

What is the good way to achieve this ?

Additional informations :
Dropbear is used for the client. Proxyhost is a regular Debian machine. Host is a Synology NAS.

Comment: In order to find out which options `rysnc` to passes to `ssh`, I created a script named `ssh` which simply writes its own arguments to a logfile. Then I put the directory with the script at the start of my path and tested the `rsync` command. What i found was that `rsync` on my machine (running Ubuntu 14.04) does not pass any `-J` option to `ssh`. So I'd say some more detail is needed in your question. What is the exact `ssh` command line, which `rsync` uses on your system? What error message does `ssh` produce?

Comment: There is no error message. On my client (here it's an Android phone), i am using Dropbear version of ssh and rsync. I am trying to reproduce the above command. But in dropbear ssh, there is no -o option. According to the documentation, it's like this : `-J <proxy_program> Use program pipe rather than TCP connection` but I did not found the proper syntax yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `-J` instead of `-o ProxyCommand`. But `-J` does not support the `%h` and `%p` notation like `ProxyCommand`. That means you will need to specify hostname and port again.

Make sure you specify the same hostname both times, otherwise it is going to fail - most likely when verifying the host key.

This command should work:

```
rsync -avz --delete -e "dbclient -J 'dbclient -B host:22 user@proxyhost'" /tmp/a-folder user@host:/tmp
```

Comment: If this doesn't work, you debug it it by testing inside out. So first verify that `dbclient -B host:22 user@proxyhost` works, next verify that `dbclient -J 'dbclient -B host:22 user@proxyhost' user@host` works.

Comment: It is not working : `ssh: Connection to user@host:22 exited: Remote closed the connection
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(600) [sender=3.0.6]` It is trying to get to the host directly, without connecting to proxy host.

Comment: @ToYonos Then you need to test the individual parts like described in the comment above.

Comment: My bad, my server was down yesterday, as my NAS (electrical outage). I just tried again your solution and it is working fine. Thanks a lot.